# Java generics auto casting

Tags: java, generics

I have this Event class that I’d like to make more generic, so I can return other types than just User, Is there a way of auto casting inside this event class or should I do it everytime outside of it?.

Do you have suggestions?

What I have

```
public class Event {
  protected String name;
  protected Pair<String, User> event;

  public String getName() {
    return event.first;
  }

  public User getData() {
    return event.second;
  }

  public Event(String name, User data) {
    event = Pair.create(name, data);
  }
}
```

What I want

```
public class Event<T> {
  protected String name;
  protected Pair<String, T> event;

  public String getName() {
    return event.first;
  }

  public T getData() {
    return event.second; //cast to type
  }

  public Event(String name, T data) {
    event = Pair.create(name, data);
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for cast (but we don't have `Pair` definition), as (it seems) `second` is of type `T` and `getData()` return a `T`.

Comment: I don't get what you want exactly. The second code you posted should work if I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Why do you think you need to cast from ``T`` to ``T``?

Comment: If I call `getData()` it will return Object, not `T` :(

Comment: That is most likely because you are using a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) in other code that you didn't show us. Don't do that - use generics all the way. In other words: wherever you are using this, use `Event<User>` instead of just `Event`.

Comment: Hey @Jesper I actually found the problem, I was posting this event in a RxBus  `public void post(Event event) {
    relaySubject.accept(event);
  }`

Comment: I need to find a way of posting a generic type event in a non generic bus now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you defined `Pair`, but the following works without any casting required:

```
public class Pair<F,S>
{
  F first;
  S second;
  public Pair (F first, S second) {
    this.first=first;
    this.second=second;
  }
  public static <F,S> Pair<F,S> create (F first, S second) {
    return new Pair<F,S> (first,second);
  }
}

public class Event<T> {
  protected String name;
  protected Pair<String, T> event;

  public String getName() {
    return event.first;
  }

  public T getData() {
    return event.second;
  }

  public Event(String name, T data) {
    event = Pair.create (name, data); // note you can use the Pair constructor directly 
                                      // instead of calling the static create method
  }
}
```

Which can be used, for example, like this:

```
Event<Integer> intEvent = new Event<> ("name", 5);
Integer data = intEvent.getData ();
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create an instance of `Event<User>`, `T` gets automatically "substituted" to `User`
So `public T getData()` actually returns an User and there is no need for casting

Comment: That's what I want but currently `getData()` returns `Object`. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's how I create the class 
`new Event<>(eventName, user)`

Comment: @LeonardoDeleon the problem is in the way you are creating the instance of the class. A correct instantiation of the class would be Event<User> event = new Event<>(eventName, user)

Comment: I'm using Android, It says that the explicit argument can be replaced for `<>`